# Homeomorphism & inverse, between $U=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} :|x|+|y|\leqslant 2 \}$ and $V=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : \max(|x|, |y|)\leqslant 3\}$

Tags: general-topology, functions, algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, inverse

Find a homeomorphism, and its inverse, between $U$ and $V$ where:

$U= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x|+|y| \leqslant 2 \}$

$V= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \max (|x|, |y|) \leqslant 3 \} $

---

I have sketched these regions and I believe $U$ is square with lengths $2$ rotated $45$ degrees through the origin, and $V$ is the square centred at the origin with length $3$

So $U \rightarrow V$ would involve a $45$ degree rotation and then a scaling of $1.5$

---

But how do I use this information to explicitly construct an homeomorphism? I am having difficulty constructing these. Also, I want to know how to construct the inverse homeomorphism too.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Rotations ans scalings are linear operations.

Comment: Both the $45^\circ$ rotation and the scaling are **invertible linear maps**. Try to find the matrix corresponding to each of these then just compose the two in the correct order. For further reference, you could google "rotation matrices."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a hint and a correction than an answer.
You need to be careful with your set $U$. They should look like the following: $U$

[image: A diamond shape with vertices on (2,0),(0,2),(-2,0), and (0,-2).]

and $V$

[image: A square with vertices at (3,3),(3,-3),(-3,-3), and (-3,3).]

I would agree with User8128 in this and say that you do want to use the combination of two invertible matrices, one a rotation and the other a scaling, which  you can find many places on the internet, but it is not a scaling by 1.5.  Be careful and see if you can figure out what the proper amount you need to scale by is, and the corresponding matrices for both transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way. You have $U = \overline{B}_1(0, 2)$, $V = \overline{B}_\infty(0, 3)$, so you could take
$\phi:U \to V$ given by $\phi(x) = {3 \over 2} {\|x\|_1 \over \|x\|_\infty} x$,
for $x \neq 0$ and $\phi(0) = 0$.

This is not as nice as the map you suggest as it is not smooth, but the general idea works between any two balls with different norms.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that hard to come with rotation matrix. Just as with any linear map, you need to see what it does to basis vectors.

Let us denote rotation by angle $\varphi$ with $R_\varphi$.

If we rotate $(1,0)$ by $\varphi$, by appealing to polar coordinates (after we sketch unit circle) we immediately get that $R_\varphi(1,0)=(\cos\varphi,\sin\varphi)$.

Since $(0,1)$ is orthogonal to $(1,0)$, and rotations preserve angles, it follows that $R_\varphi(0,1) = (\cos(\varphi+\frac\pi 2),\sin(\varphi+\frac\pi 2)) = (-\sin\varphi,\cos\varphi)$.

Thus, $R_\varphi = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\varphi & -\sin\varphi\\
\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi
\end{array}
\right)$

Considering scaling factor, I agree that $1.5$ is wrong, but I won't spoil N. Owad's intention. You can't just compare $3$ and $2$, think what those lengths represent geometrically (or just look at pictures provided in the answer by N. Owad).

Finally, your homeomorphism is $f(x) = \lambda R_\varphi x$, where $\lambda$ is the appropriate scaling factor.